# Setting an Excel cell value to a decimal in C#. Differences between .NET 2 and .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have this code (this is a simplified version of the real code) that opens excel and set the value of a cell. Please note that I am in Italy and we use **,** instead of **.** to separate the decimal digits. This means that I use 12.5 in the code, but the result of `ToString()` on this number is "12,5" and Excel shows 12,5, too.

```
using Xls = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class ExcelTest
{
    public static void Test
    {
        object hmissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        // create an instance of Excel and make it visible            
        Xls.Application anApp = new Xls.ApplicationClass();
        anApp.Visible = true;
        // add an empty workbook
        Xls.Workbooks wbks = anApp.Workbooks;
        wbks.Add(hmissing);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbks);
        // set the value of the first cell
        Decimal d = 12.5m;
        Xls.Range aRange = anApp.get_Range("A1", hmissing);
        aRange.set_Value(Xls.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, d.ToString());
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aRange);
    }
}
```

Everything has worked fine for years using .NET 2, but when I try to switch to .NET 4 Excel warns me that *the number has been stored as text*.

Please note that I know that simply avoiding to call ToString() fixes the problem, but in the real case I am dealing with a legacy application that wants to store several kinds of data in excel, both basetypes and user defined ones, and ToString() was the only method available on all these types that would give the desired result in Excel without having to check for the type and deciding what to pass to set_Value.

So I'm not asking how to modify my code in order to make it work. I'm just trying to understand why the behaviour is different in the two versions of the framework. It's quite important because I'd prefer to modify my code before the users find out that there's something wrong.

Comment: I have no clue why there is a difference between .NET 2 and .NET 4, but which version of Excel are you using? Are you sure that it is not just a Excel version difference?

Comment: It doesn't seem to depend on Excel version. I tried it with Excel 2003 and with Excel 2010 and got the same results.

Comment: I wish I knew the answer, but I do know that .NET 4 did a lot around how Interop works.  I can't find a definitive explanation, but the breaking changes around Interop raise some interesting points around the code you listed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831%28VS.100%29.aspx Namely, the embedding of interop types and how optional parameters are handled seem to hint at what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the "ToString" methode isn't set in stone and depends on the current cultureinfo your thread is running.
If you are running the program on a pc with another language pack the output can change.
Another reason could be that the current thread is set to certain culturinfo somewhere else in your code.

Please try the following example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        decimal d = 12.56m;
        // Different thread cultureinfo
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        Console.WriteLine(d);

        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat));
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat));
        Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: I'm running the example with different versions of the framework but on the same machine (with exactly the same cultureinfo). Furthermore, the result of ToString() is exactly the same and the one I'm expecting.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\test.xls", Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                                                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                                                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                                                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false,
                                                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

        decimal dec = 12.5m;
        worksheet.get_Range("A1").Value = dec;

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        worksheet.get_Range("A2").Value = date;

        string str = "Hello";
        worksheet.get_Range("A3").Value = str;

        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheet);
        workbook.Save();
        workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
        excel.Quit();
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);
```

Comment: Please note that I'm not asking how to modify ny code in order to get rid of the problem. I'd just like to know hy there is such a difference between these 2 versions of the framework so to be able to spot other possible bugs before the customers find them.